# ERROR: la columna «DiasVacaciones» es de tipo double precision pero la expresión es de tipo record LINE 2: SET "DiasVacaciones" = "subquery"

Tags: postgresql

Estoy tratando de obtener la cantidad de meses e insertar esos en una tabla que ya contiene datos..(En la misma tabla). Ya inserte en la misma tabla la fecha de entrada y la fecha solicitud, de esas 2 fechas ocupo obtener la cantidad de meses e insertarlos en la misma tabla, pero me aparece este error:

> ERROR:  la columna «DiasVacaciones» es de tipo double precision pero la expresión es de tipo record
> LINE 2: SET "DiasVacaciones" = "subquery"

```
UPDATE "Vacaciones"
SET "DiasVacaciones" = "subquery"
FROM (SELECT (DATE_PART('year', "FechaSolicitud"::date) - DATE_PART('year', "FechaEntrada"::date)) * 12 +
              (DATE_PART('month', "FechaSolicitud"::date) - DATE_PART('month', "FechaEntrada"::date)) FROM "Vacaciones") AS subquery
WHERE "Vacaciones"."NumeroIdentificacion" = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta debería ser la query (para calcular los meses entre dos fechas y actualizar la tabla):

```
UPDATE "Vacaciones"
SET "DiasVacaciones" = EXTRACT(year FROM age("FechaSolicitud", "FechaEntrada")) * 12 + EXTRACT(month FROM age("FechaSolicitud", "FechaEntrada"))
WHERE "NumeroIdentificacion" = 123;
```

Suponiendo "FechaSolicitud" > "FechaEntrada". En caso de que "FechaSolicitud" y "FechaEntrada" no sean del tipo Date, las podés castear de esta forma "FechaSolicitud"::date. Solo lo calcula para los registros que cumplen "NumeroIdentificacion" = 123.

Si querés calcular los días:

```
UPDATE "Vacaciones"
SET "DiasVacaciones" = "FechaSolicitud" - "FechaEntrada"
WHERE "NumeroIdentificacion" = 123;
```